# Share data from promise with callback of other controller

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Controller A sends a request via promise. What is the best way of running a callback function simultaniously in another controller B? Either broadcasting via service in the original callback and listen for it in the other controller. Is there a possibility in passing the promise to the controller B?

### Option 1:

```
// controller A
service.doAjax().then( function( data ) { 
// controller A callback 
// should I broadcast "data" and listen for the event in controller B ?
} );

// controller B
$rootScope.$on();
// ... listen for the event sent from controller A to get "data
```

### Option 2:

```
// controller A
var promise = service.doAjax(); 
shareService.sharePromise( promise ); // Sharing the promise with broadcast

// controller B
// get promise from shareService via $on()
promise.then( function( data) {} );
```

The problem with option 2 is that the callback function will be executed multiple times. I do not want to share the data, but execute a callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share the promise instead of sharing the data. In your service:

```
var cached = null; // assumes the ajax doesn't return a falsey value
function doAjax(){
    if(!cached) cached = $http.get(...); // actual request
    return cached;
}
```

That way, when the two controllers call it they will get the same request - and it will be actually triggered by whoever calls it first. By caching the promise (and not the data) you're also preventing a class of interesting race conditions.

If you don't want to always cache the result, you can have a special method for "who you want to wait for" implementing a sort of barrier or rendezvous pattern:

```
var awaiters = {};
function randevouz(who){
    return new $q(function(resolve, reject){
         awaiters[who] = (awaiters[who] || []).concat(resolve); // add new
    });
}
function arrived(who){
    (awaiters[who] || []).forEach(function(x){ x(); });
}
```

Which'd let you in controller B call:

```
randevouz("B").then(function(){
    // a let me know they're ready   
});
```

And in A:

```
doAjax().then(function(){
    arrived("A");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason for caching the `$http.get` ? What happens if I do not cache it? Also, what is best practice technique in this situation for sharing between controllers?

Comment: @Indianer caching a promise is fine, "best practice" is opinionated and $http.get returns a promise (I just assumed this is what doAjax does internally) - so I'm caching that and _not_ the result.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, why cache the promise? Not caching will lead to executing the callback in controller B multiple times?

Comment: It will lead to loss of synchronization and the ajax request being done several times.